# How to pass values from react to express when file handling/uploading

Tags: reactjs, express, multer, knex.js

**TLDR:** How would i be able to pass in 2 values to express from react when doing file uploading ?

I have a express route, that needs to take in 2 values `img_url`, and `image title`.

```
const img = new Image({
  img_url:result.url,
  image_title:req.body.image_title
});
```

Currently, i am able to post the `img_url` from react to express, however im having troubles posting the `image_title`. **So to make it work for now, i'm making `image_title:null`**

I am using [react-images-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-images-upload) to pass in the file

And doing this alone, passes in the img_url to the express route,

```
handleUpload =  file =>  {

    const data = new FormData()
    const image = file[0]

    console.log(this.state.image_title)
    // debugger;
    data.append('ourImage',image)
    data.append('image_title', this.state.image_title)
    Axios.post('/images/upload', data).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({
            image_url:response.data.img_url,
            // images: [...this.state.images, this.state.image_url ]
        })
    });
    console.log(this.state.image_url);
}

<ImageUploader
    withIcon={true}
    withPreview={true}
    onChange={this.handleUpload}       
    buttonText='Upload an image'
    imgExtension={['.jpg', '.gif', '.png', '.gif']}
    maxFileSize={5242880}
/>
```

However i want to pass both values image title and the img_url itself. So in my attempt i make a form like this, **but my attempt does not send the image title to the express route. My attempt gives me an error**

> POST /images/upload 500 30.398 ms - 703 [1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-images-upload) TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'path' of undefined [1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-images-upload)     at path
>   (/Users/eli/nodework/myexpressknex/routes/images.js:41:37)

**My attempt**

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleUpload}>
    <TextField
        id="outlined-name2"
        label="Image Title"
        fullWidth
        name="image_title"
        value={this.state.image_title}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        margin="normal"
    />
    <ImageUploader
        withIcon={true}
        withPreview={true}
        // onChange={this.handleUpload}
        buttonText='Upload an image'
        imgExtension={['.jpg', '.gif', '.png', '.gif']}
        maxFileSize={5242880}
    />
    <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" type="submit">
        Submit
    </Button> 
    <br></br>  
    <br></br> 
</form>
```

So, How would i be able to pass in both values to express from react when doing file uploading ?

**express route**

```
import express from 'express';
import passport from 'passport';
import multer from 'multer';
import Image from '../models/Image'
import cloudinary from 'cloudinary';
import multipart from 'connect-multiparty';
import var_dump from 'var_dump';
import dd from 'dump-die';

const multipartMiddleware = multipart();

const cloud = cloudinary.v2
const router = express.Router();

const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage }); 


cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.cloudinaryName,
    api_key: process.env.cloudinaryKey,
    api_secret: process.env.cloudinarySecret,
})


router.get('/uploads', (req, res) => {
    Image.forge().fetchAll().then( (images) => {
        res.json(images.toJSON());
    })
})


router.post('/upload',  multipartMiddleware,  upload.single('ourImage'), (req, res) => {
     if(!req.files){
         return res.status(500).send("Please upload a file");
     }
     console.log(req.files.ourImage.path)
    cloud.uploader.upload(req.files.ourImage.path, {crop: "thumb", folder: '/uploads'} ,    (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        const img = new Image({
            img_url:result.url,
            image_title:null
        });
        // console.log(img);

        img.save().then( img => {
            return res.status(200).json(img);
        });

    });
});

export default router;
```

**react side**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import ImageUploader from 'react-images-upload';
import Axios from '../Axios';
import Image from './Image';
class Dashboard extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super();
        this.state = {
            image_url: 'http://www.conservewildlifenj.org/images/artmax_1001.jpg', 
            images: [], 
            image_title:''
        }
    }
    handleUpload =  file =>  {
        const data = new FormData()
        const image = file[0]
        console.log(this.state.image_title)
        // debugger;
        data.append('ourImage',image)
        data.append('image_title', this.state.image_title)
        Axios.post('/images/upload', data).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            this.setState({
                image_url:response.data.img_url,
                // images: [...this.state.images, this.state.image_url ]
            })
        });
        console.log(this.state.image_url);
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        // e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }
    // fileOnchange = (file) => {
    //     this.setState({
    //         [file[0].target.name]: file[0].target.value
    //     })
    // }
    componentWillMount(){
        Axios.get('/images/uploads').then( (response) => {
            let img;
            Object.keys(response.data).forEach( (key) => {
                img = response.data[key].img_url
                console.log(key, img);
                this.setState({
                    images: [...this.state.images, img]
                })
            });
        })
    }
    componentDidUpdate(nextProps, prevState) {
        if (this.state.image_url !== prevState.image_url) {
          this.setState({
            images: [ this.state.image_url, ...this.state.images]
          });
        }
      }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <Grid container justify="center" spacing={16}>
                <Grid item sm={8} md={6} style={{ margin: '40px 0px', padding: '0px 30px'}}>
                    <Typography align="center" variant="h6">
                        Welcome to the Dashboard
                    </Typography>
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleUpload}>
                        <TextField
                            id="outlined-name2"
                            label="Image Title"
                            fullWidth
                            name="image_title"
                            value={this.state.image_title}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            margin="normal"
                        />
                        <ImageUploader
                            withIcon={true}
                            withPreview={true}
                            // onChange={this.handleUpload}
                            buttonText='Upload an image'
                            imgExtension={['.jpg', '.gif', '.png', '.gif']}
                            maxFileSize={5242880}
                        />
                        <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" type="submit">
                            Submit
                        </Button> 
                        <br></br>  
                        <br></br> 
                    </form>
                    {this.state.images.length > 0 ? (
                        this.state.images.map( (img, i) => (     
                            <Grid item md={8} key={i}>
                                {/* <Image image_url={this.state.image_url}/> */}
                                    <Image image_url={img} />                   
                            </Grid>
                        ))
                    ) : (
                        <div>
                            <Grid item md={8}>
                                <Typography>No Images yet</Typography>
                            </Grid>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </Grid>
                {/* Images  */}
              </Grid>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: What multipart middleware are you using?

Comment: @Garrett Motzner `const multipartMiddleware = multipart();` updated the code as well

Comment: From the docs for that module: "I actually recommend against using this module. It's cleaner to use the multiparty API directly.

This middleware will create temp files on your server and never clean them up. Thus you should not add this middleware to all routes; only to the ones in which you want to accept uploads. And in these endpoints, be sure to delete all temp files, even the ones that you don't use."

Comment: Ok, but how would i be able to pass in the image_title value from react to express, is their any examples thats similar to mine using react for file handling sending data to the backend ?

Comment: The error you are getting doesn't seem to be related to your image title. AFAICT image title should be correct....

Comment: @GarrettMotzner ok will see what i can do. Will post an answer if i come to a solution. thanks though.